# notebook difference web utility issue

Tags: python

I have installed the notebook difference utility and tried to use it like this...

```
# nbdiff-web Untitled1.ipynb  datagy_svm.ipynb
[I nbdimeserver:422] Listening on 127.0.0.1, port 44477
[W webutil:18] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[I webutil:29] URL: http://127.0.0.1:44477/diff?base=Untitled1.ipynb&remote=datagy_svm.ipynb
```

Then I try to visit http://example.com:44477/diff?base=Untitled1.ipynb&remote=datagy_svm.ipynb
and it does not load.

The problem is only with the -web and the other command works as expected without web interface.

```
nbdiff Untitled1.ipynb  datagy_svm.ipynb
```

The command mentioned above works as expected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it belongs on Stack Overflow or a data science exchange.

Comment: I’m a little confused. Are you _actually_ trying to visit `example.com`? Or are you using the correct host (`127.0.0.1`)? If so, how exactly does it not load? Timeout, connection refused, …?